# How to exchange parts of a variable name in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, replace

I try to run a chunk of code multiple times (t1-t13). Since all the variable names start with the name of the concerning timepoint, I tried to write a function in which I wanted to simply replace the “t1” in the variable name, e.g., t1_ls_3. To do so, I used the paste function to convert the following chunk of code into a function, where only the timepoint should be replaced. A short example:

I need a way to change t1 in this line:
`data$t1_ls_3 <- 11`

I tried this out and it worked:

```
data[paste(“t1”, "ls_3", sep = "_")] <- 11
data <- data[paste(“t1”, "ls_3", sep = "_")]
```

Then I tried to write it as a function:

```
func_replace <- function(x = “time”) {
  data[paste(“time”, "ls_3", sep = "_")] <- 11
  data <- data[paste(“time”, "ls_3", sep = "_")]
 
}
func_replace (x = “t1“)
```

However, all R does when I run the function is to put a new variable into the data frame, time_ls_3 and does not change the actual variable t1_ls_3.
Do you have any idea what the problem is or how I can exchange parts of a variable name in a function? I know that I could work around the problem by using a long-format data set. But I would like to know how to exchange parts of a variable in a function in general.

Comment: You've got "fancy quotes" in the code in your question, maybe some step along the way autocorrected them. For anything to work, you'll need to replace them with regular quotes.

Comment: A tidyverse solution would use `rename` or [`rename_with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906163/using-a-numlist-loop-when-renaming-variables/67906531#67906531).  You're correct to say that long-format would avoid the problem: I urge you to explore its benefits both for this issue and others.

Comment: As for your question,  you need to assign function output. `data <- func_replace(x = "t1")`. And I'd **strongly** recommend using passing `data` into the function as an argument so that you can use the function no matter what your data is called.

Comment: If you need more help, please share a few rows of data as a reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe it helps when you change `<-` to `<<-` in the function.

Comment: Originally I used <<-, unfortunately this did not work

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental misunderstanding seems to be about character strings and symbols.

You define a character string in R with `"` or `'`. Thus the following:

```r
"time"
```

is a character string with the word time in it.

In contrast, symbols are names that can refer to objects in R. You can create a symbol (pointing to an object) holding a time called time like this:

```r
time <- "03:00"
```

When you type `time` at the console, you get back the character string:

```r
time
#"03:00"
```

Therefore, when you try to use `paste` with `"time"`, you're going to get the same result no matter what:

```
paste("time", "ls_3", sep = "_")
#[1] "time_ls_3"
```

Instead, you seem to want to use `x` which is the symbol your function is assigning `"t1"` to.

Perhaps your data looks something like this:

```
data <- setNames(data.frame(t(rep(0,5))),sapply(1:5,\(x)paste0("t",x,"_ls_3")))
data
#  t1_ls_3 t2_ls_3 t3_ls_3 t4_ls_3 t5_ls_3
#1       0       0       0       0       0
```

The last problem is that assignments inside functions only work in the function environment, so you need to use the `<<-` operator.

```
func_replace <- function(x = NULL) {
  data[paste(x, "ls_3", sep = "_")] <<- 11
  }

func_replace(x = “t1“)
data
#  t1_ls_3 t2_ls_3 t3_ls_3 t4_ls_3 t5_ls_3
#1      11       0       0       0       0
```